# samba do not show hidden dot files

Tags: samba

using Samba between a linux server and a windows 10 pc client.
From windows I go to `\\mylinuxserver` and go into my home folder and see

```
.cache/
.gconf/
.gvfs/
.mozilla/
and so on
Desktop/
Downloads/
my_folders_i_care_about/
```

I don't want to see all the dot folders and files like `.cache`.
I don't want to see `.anything` in windows explorer when navigating into a samba share.  How can I stop dot files and dot folders from being visible?

My `smb.conf` is currently this for sharing out home directories and any other folder; this is under SLES11 with samba 3.6 but I will be using RHEL 7.6 eventually.

```
[homes]
    comment = Home Directories
    valid users = %S, %D%w%S
    browseable = No
    read only = No
    inherit acls = Yes
    create mask = 660
    directory mask = 770
[data]
    path = /data
    create mask = 660
    directory mask = 770
    inherit acls = Yes
    read only = No
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this. If you just want to hide these files (they will still be accessible, if the user(s) know what their names are), add this parameter:

```
hide files = /.*/
```

To make them completely invisible to the Samba user, do this:

```
veto files = /.*/
```

FYI - these settings must be put in the section that defines each share; they are not global parameters.

Comment: for me in samba 3.6 only `veto files = /.*/` seemed to prevent them from being visible.  Tthe `hide files` had no affect.

Comment: I've only tested it on the 4.x branch; maybe the `hide files` option is new.

Comment: only `veto files = /.*/` seems to work in rhel 7.9 currently with samba-4.10.16-9.el7_9.x86_64.  The `hide files` had no affect.

Comment: Interesting...on my LM 20 system (Samba v4.11.6), the `hide files =` option looks legit; here's the example from the man page: `hide files = /.*/DesktopFolderDB/TrashFor%m/resource.frk/`.

Comment: you are saying samba v4.11.6   My RHEL 7.9 system right now is samba-4.10.  Is there a version hard line with samba where this begins working?  In any case the `veto files` is working for me.

Comment: Couldn't tell you. Tbh, I don't remember what version of Samba I was using when I wrote my answer.

Comment: A quick look around suggests that these [options were present](https://samba.samba.narkive.com/trJAyVp5/hiding-and-vetoing-files-for-samba-2-2-2-windows-explorer) even as far back as Samba 2.2.2

Comment: `hide (dot) files` only sets "hidden" attribute to that files. If Explorer has "Show hidden files" option enabled then that files are still visible (but in tinted colors).

Answer (score 1):

As of version 4.11.6 you can use `hide dot files` parameter.

It would look something like this:

```
[data]
    path = /data
    read only = No
    hide dot files = yes
```

Comment: this does not work currently on rhel 7.9 with samba-**4.10**.16-9.el7_9.x86_64.  will keep an eye out for samba update, thanks.

Comment: Strange it perfectly works for me on Ubuntu 20.04